# Set Response Status code in View Component

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to set Status Code in View Component so that i can check that in .ts file.

Here is my .ts file code

```
window.onload = function () {

    fetch('../Controller/ActionName',
        {
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("Token")).value
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status != 200) {
                redirectToHomePage();
            }
            response.text().then((data) => {
                document.getElementById("Id")!.innerHTML = data;
            });
        });

    // Redirect to home page
    function redirectToHomePage() {
        var url = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = url + '/Login/Login/';
    }
};
```

Action will call ViewComponent and get back response
then i want to check if there is no error in view component then it will be 200 
and if there is error in view component then it will be any other error code.

Below is the ViewComponent code

```
protected IViewComponentResult TestViewComponent()
{
    try
    {
        // Do code here
    }
    Catch(Exception ex){                
        return View(viewName)
    }

    return View(viewName);
}
```

I want to set status code in catch block.

Please help me with that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Are not reachable directly as an HTTP endpoint. They're invoked from
>   your code (usually in a view). A view component never handles a
>   request.

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-component-methods), the component never handles a request, view component methods are overloaded on the signature rather than any details from the current HTTP request. So you couldn't directly return the status codes inside the  view component. If you want to return the custom status codes inside the view component it's impossible.

You should modify the codes to move the check logic into the controller action not the  view component like below:

```
public IActionResult LoadVisit(int? id)
{

    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var model = new VisitViewModel();
    try
    {
        model = await visitAPI.GetVisit(clientID, visitID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Error message");
    }

    return ViewComponent("ClientVisit", model });

}
```

But if you directly throw an exception inside the view components, the client side will receive 500 error not 200.

Like below test demo:

```
public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ToDoContext db;

    public PriorityListViewComponent(ToDoContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
    {
        return db.ToDo.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone &&
                             x.Priority <= maxPriority).ToListAsync();
    }
    #region snippet1
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        int maxPriority, bool isDone)
    {
        string MyView = "Default";
        // If asking for all completed tasks, render with the "PVC" view.
        if (maxPriority > 3 && isDone == true)
        {
            MyView = "PVC";
        }
        try
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(MyView, items);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: as return type is IViewComponentResult so it is not possible to use return StatusCode(500);

Comment: As far as I know, the component never handles a request, view component methods are overloaded on the signature rather than any details from the current HTTP request.  So you should move the check logic out of the view component and into the controller and then pass the resultant data into the view component if there is no exception. See my update method. We will call the ViewComponent inside a controller action.

Comment: Besides, if you directly throw the error in the ViewComponent codes, the client side will receive 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but I wanted to add my suggestion to that question too, Brando Zhang explained well. ViewComponent is not intented to handle request so we can't set response code directly in ViewComponent declaration. You can handle this situatuion by setting StatusCode property in your action

```
public IActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
     var viewComponent = ViewComponent("YourViewComponentName");
     viewComponent.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; //set desired status code
     return viewComponent; 
}
```